# Using a String in Place of a Class to Access a Method, Function, or Attribute Inside of It?

Tags: python, class

OK, so heres what I'm trying to do:

```
    class MyClass(object):      #Class I want to access
    """MyClass, base class for my class"""
    def __init__(self, numberOfApples):
        numberOfApples = 12     #Attribute I plan to use

myClassString = "MyClass"

#What I'm trying to do:

if myClassString.numberOfApples >= 12:   """myClassString is in place of the real class name, MyClass"""
    print "Wow, you got alot of apples!"
```

And what I'm trying to do is seeing if it is possible to reference an attribute of a class by using a string in place of the actual class name. Is this possible? If not, what's the closest thing I can get? Thanks.

Comment: closet and best would be create a dictionary, mapping strings to classes.

Comment: Just create the instance of the class. Otherwise, myClassString is a string

Comment: The marked duplicate will show you how to retrieve attributes using a string.  You can theoretically acccomplish something very similiar by using `locals()` to retrieve things in the namespace, but realistically that's usually a design anti-pattern.